# CSS to toggle the bootstrap-vue card full screen

Tags: css, bootstrap-vue

I have two charts(Apex) inside two bootstrap-vue cards, I want to put a button on each card which upon clicking should make my individual card full screen. Everything is set up but my CSS to make it full screen is not working.

When uncommenting the below CSS in my sandbox(link is given below), It makes my cards overlapped.

```
  div.card-body.sessionInfo {
  display: block;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Sandbox link is here : [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-moon-6dbgn?file=/src/App.vue:845-1029)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the browsers built-in functionality to open a HTML element in fullscreen.

Forked sandbox:
https://hr9i9.csb.app/

```html
<b-container fluid>
  <b-row>
    <b-col>
      <b-card class="mt-2">
        <b-card ref="graph-1" body-class="sessionInfo">
          <b-card-title>Session Graph</b-card-title>
          <div>
            <b-button @click="toggleFullscreen('graph-1')" size="sm">
              <b-icon-arrows-angle-expand></b-icon-arrows-angle-expand>
            </b-button>
          </div>
        </b-card>
        <!-- second card -->
        <b-card ref="graph-2" body-class="errorInfo" class="mt-1">
          <b-card-title>Error Graph</b-card-title>
          <div>
            <b-button @click="toggleFullscreen('graph-2')" size="sm">
              <b-icon-arrows-angle-expand></b-icon-arrows-angle-expand>
            </b-button>
          </div>
        </b-card>
      </b-card>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

```js
methods: {
  toggleFullscreen(ref) {
    const elem = this.$refs[ref];
    // Note: this fullscreen check does not work on IE11
    const isFullscreen = document.fullscreenElement !== null;

    if (isFullscreen) {
      this.closeFullscreen()
    } else {
      this.openFullscreen(elem)
    }
  },
  openFullscreen(elem) {
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
      elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  },
  closeFullscreen() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Hiws, It does work on desktop but failed on mobile devices. It says,TypeError
Failed to execute 'exitFullscreen' on 'Document': Document not active.

Comment: The check for full screen (`const isFullscreen = window.innerHeight === screen.height`), might not work on mobile devices. You could try finding an alternative to checking whether the page is fullscreened or not.

Comment: @skr I've edited the answer and updated the sandbox, looks to work on mobile now. (At least android/chrome)